# MySQL adding extra rows to a selection

Tags: numbers

Is it possible to format somehow the MySQL SELECT query, so if the records contain nonconsecutive numbers, the missing numbers to be added accordingly, i.e. if the database contains

```
765
767
768
769
772
773
778
779
780
```

the returned query to look like this:

```
765
766
767
768
769
770
771
772
773
774
775
776
777
778
779
780
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to get the consecutive numbers from a dummy table and LEFT JOIN the two tables.